# How to calculate inertia tensor of composite shape?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

How can I calculate inertia tensor of composite shape. I have done math of moment of inertia, but not inertia tensor.

Can anyone help me with the calculation of this shape :

[image: inertia of composite shape]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

you can use the parallel axes theory :

$$I=I_1+I_2+I_3-m_1 \,\tilde{r}_{01}\,\tilde{r}_{01}-m_3\,\,\tilde{r}_{03}\,\tilde{r}_{03}$$

where :

$$\tilde{r}_{01}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & -z & 0 \\
   z & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

and
$$\tilde{r}_{03}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & +z & 0 \\
   -z & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: what are the value of  $I_x$ and $I_y$ ?

Comment: Sorry for that The result is I which is the inertia tensor $3\times3$ symmetric matrix

Comment: I took the * out , the result is the same as the first version.

Comment: Can you take a look [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505602/how-to-calculate-inertia-tensor-of-composite-shape-with-angle), please ..

Comment: if I translate and move the whole object downward and then calculate the inertia tensor, what will be changed. I want to put the plane on the center of origin. I'm confused with those `+/-` signs. @Eli

Comment: the result is the same if you take +z or -z because you multiply $\tilde{r}\,\tilde{r}$ which is the same for +z or -z